# Boolean of show() or hide() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code. i what that if my `div{display:block} alert('yes')` esle
`div{display:none} alert('no')`

```
<div class="C-1"></div>

<script>
if ( Boolean ( $('.C-1').show() ) == true ) { alert('yes' }
if ( Boolean ( $('.C-1').show() ) == false ) { alert('no') }
</script>
```

or

```
if ( Boolean ( $('.C-1').css({'display':'block'}) ) == true ) { alert('yes' }
if ( Boolean ( $('.C-1').css({'display':'block'}) ) == false ) { alert('no') }
```

but this code doesn't work !

So what do u suggest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:visible` and `:hidden` pseudo-selectors.

To check if the element is `visible`:

```
$('.C-1').is(':visible')
```

This will return `true` if the element `.C-1` is visible, `false` otherwise.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

To check if element is hidden:

```
$('.C-1').is(':hidden')
```

This will return `true` if the element `.C-1` is hidden, `false` otherwise.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

**Your code**

```
if ($('.C-1').is(':visible')) {
    alert('Yes');
} else {
    alert('No');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.is()` along with `:visible` selector:

```
if($('.C-1').is(':visible')){
  alert('yes'); 
}else{
  alert('no');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with **is(':visible')**.

If you have check div is visible or not use `:visible` and div is hidden use `:hidden` psudeo selector in jquery

```
if($('.C-1').is(':visible')){
   // div is visible
}
else {
   // div is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.C-1').css('display') === 'none'){
   //hidden
}else{
   // shown
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words to your answer to explain how your code snippet does answer he OP question